# XFCE fullscreen apps go to background when not in focus

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor, fullscreen, focus

My desktop is running xfce4, and I have sloppy focus, and a multi-monitor setup.

When I move the mouse off a fullscreen window (to the other monitor) (be it the web browser in full screen, or an image viewer in presentation mode etc...), the fullscreen window on the initial monitor goes to the background, all other normal windows are now in front of it.

Or, to describe it differently, as soon as the full screen window loses focus, it goes into the background.

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Is this the same issue as tracked [here](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/697)?

Comment: I think current xfce4 now doesn’t show that behavior anymore. At least testing with mplayer fullscreen or firefox fullscreen.